# Database is unauthenticated to restore back-up

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have used this script to restore the database back-up.

Step:1

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Step:2

```
BACKUP DATABASE DataBaseName
TO DISK = 'DataBaseName Path (Local Drive)'
GO
BACKUP LOG DataBaseName
TO DISK = 'DataBaseName Path (Local Drive)'
GO
```

Comment: Maybe better asked over at [dba.se].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Restore DB Just Used Below query

```
USE MASTER
GO
RESTORE DATABASE DBName FROM DISK = 'E:DBName.bak' WITH REPLACE
```